# Delay on-click div replacement

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

When the area in div 1 is clicked it is replaced with div 2 instantly. How do I add a 10 second delay between the transition?

```
<div id = "div1" style="display:block" onclick = "replace()">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ipsum leo, scelerisque at dapibus ac, consectetur vel ipsum. </div>
<div id = "div2" style="display:none">Cras suscipit ullamcorper elit vitae sodales. Sed euismod felis molestie lorem gravida a venenatis risus sollicitudin. Proin accumsan lorem in est adipiscing faucibus. </div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function replace() {
document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function of javascript.
Change your replace function to:

```
function replace() {
document.getElementById("div1").style.display="none";
setTimeout( function(){
document.getElementById("div2").style.display="block";}, 10000);
}
```